# VirtualHost causing trouble with $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']

Tags: php, apache, virtualhost

I'm using XAMPP in macOS (OS X) with **Apache 2.4.25** and PHP 7.1.6, and I created a virtualhost at the `httpd-vhosts.conf` file.

This is how I created the virtualhost:

```
<Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mysite/">
    Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<VirtualHost mysite.dev:443>
DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mysite/"
ServerName mysite.dev
ServerAlias www.mysite.dev

SSLEngine on

SSLCertificateFile "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/my_certs/mysite.dev/cert.pem"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/my_certs/mysite.dev/key.pem"

<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>
<Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>

BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
CustomLog "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/logs/ssl_request_log" \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
ErrorLog "logs/mysite.dev_ssl-error_log"
</VirtualHost>
```

I also added the virtual domain in my OS X `hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1 mysite.dev
```

If I enter to `https://mysite.dev` **everything is working as expected, but** if I enter from other computer (connected in same network) to `10.0.2.2` (local IP of the machine with XAMPP running) seems like the PHP variable `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is different:

From virtualhost URL: `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mysite/`

From IP: `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs`

If I echo `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` in the final online page (server), returns this: `/home/123456/domains/mysiteonline.com/html` which looks similar to the *IP echo*, so that's why I guess the problem is the `DocumentRoot` inside the virtualhost.

Is there any way to avoid this problem? Or at least fix it? I need that virtualhost for check domain and HTTPS configuration while developing in local.

If you need any other information, please just ask for it in the comments.

Comment: You need `10.0.2.2 mysite.dev` in the `hosts` file.

Comment: Thanks @barmar - that's causing problems with SSL/TLS, even if those self-signed certificates where made with the domain and never the IP.

Comment: The other thing you could try is `<VirtualHost 10.0.2.2:443>`

Comment: Same issue, Chrome shows "Your connection is not private", previously was showing "This site can’t provide a secure connection". This happens only at `mysite.dev` and not at `10.0.2.2`.

Comment: Make the certificate for the IP as well.

Comment: I'm gonna try. The thing is, do you think the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` or the `DocumentRoot ` has something to do with this problem?

Comment: Is your certificate self signed? If so you'd expect Chrome to warn that the connection isn't private

Comment: @JimmyAdaro The problem is that the URL they connect to isn't matching the `VirtualHost`, so it's not executing the `DocumentRoot` statement that sets the correct root.

Comment: The certificate works fine, doesn't seem to be the problem. The issue happens without HTTPS too.

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/questions/352148/apache-virtualhost-answering-when-i-browse-to-ip-address

Comment: Have you set `NameVirtualHost` for port 443? If so maybe try setting it and use `<VirtualHost *:443>`.